# Java length of subarray

Tags: java, arrays

So I have following code:

```
private float[][] data;
...
public int getSizeY() {
    return data[0].length;
}
```

But it gives me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `data.length == 0`. Is there another way or should I just store it after initialization?

Comment: How and where are you initializing your array?

Comment: i bet you have empty array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays in Java don't need to have a fixed size for the second dimension.
Therefore it is not possible to determine the size if `data.length == 0`. You have to handle that case specifically like it is shown in the other answers.

For example this is possible:

```
float[][] data = new float[2][];
data[0] = new float[5];
data[1] = new float[9];
```

Answer (score 11):

You have no x to determine what the y should be.  You can do this instead.

```
public int getSizeY() {
    return data.length < 1 ? 0 : data[0].length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java multidimensional arrays are [Iliffe vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliffe_vector), which means that each dimensional part is an independent array object of one dimension less. This gives considerable flexibility to the array shape. `data[0].length` doesn't need to be related to `data[1].length`, or `data[n].length`. For example, here's a small triangular array: `float[][] data = { new float[1], new float[2], new float[3] };` You could even have an array where some rows/columns/sub-arrays are null, or where some sub-arrays are the same objects as each other.

Since multidimensional arrays aren't restricted to simple extensions of rectangles or cuboids, it's not well-defined to ask about the length of any particular sub-array when there aren't any; hence the error. After a successful initialization like `float[][] data = new float[0][y];`, the y value is not kept. If you need to keep the 'y' when x is 0, you have to store it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `data.length>0` before doing anything with `data[0]`.

A possible way to change your code is:

```
 public int getSizeY() {
      if(data.length>0)
           return data[0].length;
      return -1; //-1 here is a note to us: oh oh! we have an error
      }
```

Comment: The length of each subarray is not necessarily the same. You can still have an error. Else, returning -1 does not tell much about the error. Better to let the funciton throw.